# unordered_map, why some buckets have more than 1 element even hashed values are all different?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-map

I am playing with default hash function for `std::unordered_map` and checking if there are collisions happening. Here below is the code:

```
void check(std::map<long, bool> & mp, const string & s, const long v){
    if(mp.count(v) == 0){
        mp[v] = true;
    }else{
        cout<<"collision for "<<s<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    std::unordered_map<std::string, long> um;
    std::map<long, bool> map;
    auto hasher = um.hash_function();

    std::string str = "";

long count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        str = char(65+i);
        um[str];
        auto value = hasher(str);
        check(map, str, value);

        for (int j = 0; j < 26; ++j)
        {
            str = char(65+i);
            str += char(65+j);
            um[str];
            auto value = hasher(str);
            check(map, str, value);

            for (int k = 0; k < 26; ++k)
            {
                str = char(65+i);
                str += char(65+j);
                str += char(65+k);
                um[str];
                auto value = hasher(str);
                check(map, str, value);

                for (int l = 0; l < 26; ++l)
                {
                    str = char(65+i);
                    str += char(65+j);
                    str += char(65+k);
                    str += char(65+l);
                    um[str];
                    auto value = hasher(str);
                    check(map, str, value);

                    for (int m = 0; m < 26; ++m)
                    {
                        str = char(65+i);
                        str += char(65+j);
                        str += char(65+k);
                        str += char(65+l);
                        str += char(65+m);
                        um[str];
                        auto value = hasher(str);
                        check(map, str, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        for(int i = 0; i < um.bucket_count(); ++i){
        if(um.bucket_size(i) >= 2)cout<<"um_collison happened at "<<i<<"  "<<um.bucket_size(i)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is I found that, there is no output for `collision for`, but there are plenty of outputs like `um_collison happened at 17961055  3`, I am using `g++ 4.9.2`, why the strings are hashed to different values but some buckets still have more than 1 element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by the hasher function is a size_t. The hasher function is assumed to give at least weakly pseudorandom (i.e. "pairwise independent" or similar) output when given a random input. However, the output of the hasher function is not used directly as the bin number of a given input. That would require that std::unordered_map has 2^64 bins on a 64 bit machine... which is way too much memory.

Instead, based on the current number of elements, there are a certain number of bins, say B. The map will take the output of the hasher, modulo B, usually, to map the items to bins. Thus items with different hashes can go to the same bin. Once the hash table gets too tightly packed, depending on some heuristics, usually B will be increased and the items will get rehashed to reduce the number of collisions. That is, we recompute all the hashes and then take them modulo B' instead for some larger B'. But how exactly it works is an implementation detail.

Comment: What shall I do if I want to avoid any single collision? According to what you said, customizing the `unordered_map` with a new hasher is likely not going to work.

Comment: So usually when you use a hash map, you don't try to perfectly avoid collisions. That basically takes more time and energy than you save and defeats the purpose. Instead you use the idea that as long as the hash function does a good job of scattering the elements, there are not *that many* collisions. According to the birthday paradox, if you have N buckets and you hash N^{1/2} things pairwise independently, you have a constant probability to have no collisions at all. So you could try to set the capacity of the hash table to use a lot of bins. But the built-in heuristics are probably better.

Comment: Your argument makes sense. But I am in a concurrency situation, different threads are adding elements to the map, so to avoid race condition without resorting to a lock, I want to eliminate collision absolutely.

Comment: I think just eliminating collisions isn't enough then. Because what if two threads are adding things at the same time and one of them triggers a reallocation / rehash into new bins. The other one is going to be manipulating a corrupted data structure.

Comment: I think somewhere there need to be some locks. For instance here's something you can do. Make a type which represents a "small bin", maybe using a std::vector. And this one gets locked / unlocked using a mutex when it is used. Then at the start of your application you make a bunch of these and put them in a hashtable, and you never destroy them or make new ones. The threads find them from the hash table (without changing it) and then lock the bin once they've found it. There might be a pre-existing solution like this, I'm not sure.

Comment: I can reserve a certain amount of buckets first and make sure rehashing is not possible in my case by calculating the maximum possible load factor for my problem.

Comment: @Allanqunzi: you can't portably avoid locking even if your hash function and pre-sizing avoid collisions, as insertions affect other variables like the "size" of the container which must be updated and read in a thread-safe fashion, and if you lookup an element from one thread that was inserted from another thread, you need some kind of memory barrier to ensure the updates are fully visible.  You should consider other approaches, like dividing the keys into N groups based on their numeric range or first character, then having a properly-locked hash table for each.